# Search box with query suggestion

Tags: sharepoint-server, search-results

I'd like to know how configure the search box suggestion to only show the value of a certain managed property?

And then how can I add a value in suggestion when I enter a search?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you don't want to use query suggestions but want to search a specific managed property, or search as you type. I would do this with JQuery.

1. Create a input control
2. Wire up JQuery to your Search Searvice
3. Fire a query with the request "MyManagedProp:Value" and then parse
   the result into items you display.

Jan has a great write-up on this approach: http://weblogs.asp.net/jan/sharepoint-search-as-you-type-with-jquery

Answer (score 1):

Are you using SharePoint 2013 ? If I understand your first question correctly, the suggestions that will be displayed in your search box can only be the values from a particular managed property.

I am not sure if we can configure this directly. However what you can do is, get all the values from your managed property, export a CSV file out of it and import it into the query suggestions

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj721441(v=office.15).aspx
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/nadeemis/archive/2012/12/20/manually-adding-search-query-suggestions-in-sharepoint-2013-using-powershell.aspx

Comment: I'm using 2010. Are there a way to manage this sugestion without PowerShell? i'm in sandbox solution :-(